# Group by string optimization

Tags: php, database, optimization, group-by

I'm gonna convert string to integer to optimize group by performance.

What do you guys think of the idea?

If applicable,then is there a built-in function to convert string to a unique integer in PHP?

Comment: you can use crc32() function to create a unique integer of a string. or use md5 then convert from hexadecimal back to base-10.

Comment: If the data is only integers, why are you storing it in string columns in the first place?  Have you measured the performance cost or benefit?

Comment: @Mauris: CRC-32 only gives you a reasonable probability of generating a unique integer for each string - it is by no means 100% deterministic.  Quite small samples can run into collisions - different strings hashing to the same CRC-32 value.  Using a bigger hash - MD5 (128 bits instead of 32 bits) or SHA-1 (160 bits) or SHA-256 (err, would you believe 256 bits) - is more likely to be unique but the conversion cost is considerably higher.

Comment: @Mauris: I was using a CRC algorithm on time zone names from the Olson database, and got collisions in that set.  Thinking back, I'm not sure now whether I was trying a 16-bit or a 32-bit CRC, but in a sample of a few hundred names, I was running into collisions.

Answer (score 4):

If all data in that column is int, then it should be int...

The main advantage you get is that a comparison between 2 ints only needs to compare 4 byte. A string that expresses the same number will (usually) be longer. So you should be able to get some performance out of it. But the main reason should be that a column that stoes int should be int.

The group by optimization would fall into the category "premature optimization"... And the main thing that will speed up a group by clause is not the datatype, but the index on the field